# Devise and Ruby on Rails: On Sign Up All Validations fail with "Can't be Blank"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am trying to sign up an `Affiliate` using Devise.

**/affiliates/registrations_controller.rb**

```
class Affiliates::RegistrationsController < 
    Devise::RegistrationsController
    include StatesHelper, ApplicationHelper

    before_action :configure_sign_up_params, only: [:create]
    before_action :configure_account_update_params, only: [:update]

    # GET /resource/sign_up
    def new
        @plan = AffiliatePlan.find_by(nickname: params.permit(:plan)[:plan].downcase)
        super
    end

    # GET /resource/edit
    def edit
        @states = us_states
        super
    end

    # PUT /resource
    def update
        @states = us_states
        super
        if resource.address_coordinates.length > 1 
            resource.services.each{ |s| s.update_attributes( {lonlat: "POINT(#{resource.address_coordinates.join(' ')})"})}
        end 
    end

    def update_resource(resource, params)
        resource.update_without_password(params)
    end

    protected

    # If you have extra params to permit, append them to the sanitizer.
    def configure_sign_up_params
        devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:business_name, :website, :phone, :affiliate_plan_id, contact_name: [:first_name, :last_name], address: [:street_address, :address_line2, :city, :state, :zip_code]])
    end

    # If you have extra params to permit, append them to the sanitizer.
    def configure_account_update_params
        devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:account_update, keys: [:business_name, :website, :phone, :affiliate_plan_id, contact_name: [:first_name, :last_name], address: [:street_address, :address_line2, :city, :state, :zip_code]])
    end

    # The path used after sign up.
    def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
        affiliate_signups_path
    end
end
```

**/affiliates/registrations/new.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>

    <%= devise_error_messages! %>

    <% if @plan %>
        <%= f.hidden_field :affiliate_plan_id, value: @plan.id %>
    <% else %>
        <%= f.hidden_field :affiliate_plan_id, value: resource.affiliate_plan_id %>
    <% end %>

    <%= f.fields_for :contact_name do |n| %>

        <%= n.text_field :first_name, autofocus: true, placeholder: "First Name*", class: "form-control", required: true %>

        <%= n.text_field :last_name, placeholder: "Last Name*", class: "form-control", required: true  %>
     <% end %>

    <%= f.text_field :business_name, placeholder: "Company Name", class: "form-control" %>

    <%= f.email_field :email, autocomplete: "email", placeholder: "Email Address*", class: "form-control", required: true %>

    <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "new-password", placeholder: "Create a Password", class: "form-control", required: true %>

    <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, autocomplete: "new-password", placeholder: "Confirm Password", class: "form-control", required: true %>


    <%= f.submit "Next", class: "btn btn-primary btn-sm" %>
<% end %>
```

**routes.rb**

```
devise_for :affiliates, path: "partners", controllers: {
  sessions: 'affiliates/sessions',
  registrations: 'affiliates/registrations'
}
```

When submitting the form I always get validation errors:

```
7 errors must be fixed
   - Email can't be blank
   - Password can't be blank
   - Password is too short (minimum is 9 characters)
   - Password must contain at least one digit
   - Password must contain at least one punctuation mark or symbol
   - Password must contain at least one upper-case letter
   - Affiliate plan must exist
```

The log shows an immediate rollback, but no other information:

```
Started POST "/partners" for 127.0.0.1 at 2020-05-25 14:09:59 -0400
Processing by Affiliates::RegistrationsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"SowYVWzTqVYdwZWjYjNc3hlGC5UITqt+bKjQuSATOpLcdVGb52x7gEi8p15MmhlZrLNLpD07fCxp5Gya8/cQMg==", "affiliate"=>{"affiliate_plan_id"=>"2", "contact_name"=>{"first_name"=>"Stephen", "last_name"=>"Tilly"}, "business_name"=>"1995", "email"=>"sarwerera@email.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Next"}
(0.2ms)  BEGIN
  ↳ app/controllers/affiliates/registrations_controller.rb:18
   (0.2ms)  ROLLBACK
  ↳ app/controllers/affiliates/registrations_controller.rb:18
  Rendering affiliates/registrations/new.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered affiliates/registrations/new.html.erb within layouts/application (2.6ms)
```

I'm not quite sure where to go from there, any ideas?

Comment: I'd start looking here https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/registrations_controller.rb#L17 . Are you able to put a break point with a debugger? Maybe something goes wrong with the param sanitization...

Comment: @Joel_Blum yes, I've but a breakpoint in the `create` method and checked the params, everything seems correct: `{"email"=>"sarwerera@email.com",
 "password"=>"Password1!",
 "password_confirmation"=>"Password1!",
 "business_name"=>"1995",
 "affiliate_plan_id"=>"2",
 "contact_name"=>{"first_name"=>"Stephen", "last_name"=>"Tilly"}}`

Comment: Have you figured this out yet?

Comment: @Eyeslandic nope. I ended up overwriting the create to do it manually, but it feels very hacky and I still have no clue why the params weren't working

Comment: Just to be sure, are you calling `configure_sign_up_params` in a `before_action` in your controller?

Comment: @Eyeslandic I have `before_action :configure_sign_up_params, only: [:create]`

Comment: Perhaps u can show your entire controller's code?

Comment: @NoNonsense I've now included the full controller

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume you have another Devise resource setup which is why you've created this setup. I'll assume it's `User`. In that case one of the main reasons could be that Devise is expecting that model as the resource which is why it's throwing erros about missing validations. Since `Devise::RegistrationsController` is expecting a `params[:user]` containing the e-mail and password.

Suggestion: If that's the case I would consider associating the Affiliate profile to the existing resource and go on from there. I.e. Affiliate -> belongs:to -> User. It would make your life easier.

Answer (score 0):

I think this may work.

We assume that an Affiliate does not have a plan, because he has not yet registered. `The Plan must exist!`

In the file `new.html.erb` it is not recommended to use logic, if you want, you can do it in the controller. Sample: `before_action :set_plan, only: [:new]`

```
class Affiliates::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  include StateHelper, ApplicationHelper

  before_action :set_plan, only: [:new]
  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, only: [:create]

  protected
    def set_plan
      @plan = AffiliatePlan.find_by(nickname: params[:plan])
    end

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up) do |user_params|
      user_params.permit([
        :email, :password, :password_confirmation,
        :business_name, :website, :phone, :affiliate_plan_id,
        contact_name: [:first_name, :last_name],
        address: [:street_address, :address_line2, :city, :state, :zip_code]
      ])
    end
  end
end
```

On the other hand, it would be great if you separated the extra information of the Affiliate from the information of the Affiliate as a user.

Example:

For the User:

> Affiliate data is: email, password, password_confirmation, username, etc

For the extra info of Affiliate:

> Affiliate Info data is: :business_name, :website, :phone, etc

Comment: I got it! You should not use the line literally, you must modify it with your parameter. `@plan = AffiliatePlan.find_by(nickname: params.permit(:plan)[:plan].downcase)`

Comment: @SaraTibbetts Did you manage to solve the problem? If you need more information, do not hesitate to request it.

Comment: I still get that all of the fields are blank. It seems the params aren't being properly permitted

Comment: It would be great if you can show the error that appears on the console.

Comment: There is no error in the console, simply a ROLLBACK

Comment: I understand, could you show the `parameters` that reach the `controller`? the ones that appear on the `console`.
Anything that can help solve it, it would be great to know.